# Prove certain probability is 0 given property of expected value

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ a random variable such that $E|X|^m \leq AC^m$ for every integer $m\geq 0$ and some positive constants $A$ and $C$. I want to show $P(|X|>c)=0$. Does anyone has some hint?

Comment: Try with Markov's inequality (with $c>C$).

Comment: $|X|>C+\epsilon$ implies $|X|^{m}>(C+\epsilon)^{m}$.